# WebDeploy - Connection String TFS2017

Tags: connection-string, webdeploy

In my WebConfig I have the following connection String.

```
<connectionStrings>

   <add name="Name" connectionString="Url=hSomeURL; Domain=SomeDomain; Username=UserName; Password=YYYYY;"

</connectionStrings>
```

In my pub.pubxml file I am trying to transform this String with the Env variables from my Release definition for Username,password and Domain. Could I call this connection string from a parameters.xml file? I tried adding this to my Web.Release.Config file but it did not work `xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using a right format such as the name matches the auto generated connection string name  in the `parameters.xml`. A sample:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter name="Username" value="xxx">
    <parameterEntry type="XMLFile" scope="web.config$" match="//configuration/connectionStrings/site/@xxx"/>
  </parameter>
```

For more details, you could take a look at this blog: [How to build a connection string from other parameters within MSDeploy packages to avoid repeating yourself in Release Management variables](https://forums.iis.net/t/1232843.aspx?Update%20ConnectionString%20in%20web%20config%20using%20MSDeploy)